# How to execute an external handler function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rendering

How to execute an external handler function that manages clicking interactions, inside another function?
I have a rendering function, which renders my HTML dynamically. In another file, I have defined a control script which handles the HTML generating. Inside the rendering function I want to call a function (defined in the control script) which handles clicking interactions. Any solutions?

Comment: Van you provide the code, please? Generally, you just need to call the function from inside of your rendering one, but having some code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It is a contract: Every javascript file your page includes becomes part of the document's global javascript content.

So if you first include the file with the clickhandler-function and then the file with the rendering function, you can call the clickhandler-function in the rendering function like for example

HTML

```
<div id="bodySimulation">
    I'm the body.
</div>
```

JS

```
/* simulation of first javascript file */
function clickHandler(domElement) {
    alert(domElement.innerHTML);
}

/* simulation of second javascript file */
function renderDiv(content) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = content;
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
        clickHandler(this);
    });
    document.getElementById("bodySimulation").appendChild(div);
}
renderDiv("a div");
renderDiv("another div");
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunnar/nphsgtrx/)